# set background image for objectchoicefield in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

How to set background image and how to set width and height for `ObjectChoiceField` in blackberry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to ask google before you ask the question on stackoverflow :)  Btw, Here is a sample code which will let you know how to set images as background for the `objectchoicefield` Here is the [Sample code](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/239646-how-customize-objectchoicefield.html)